# jQuery + Bootstrap Grid - Show Images based on screen size

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a web project and I use bootstrap's grid system. In my current set up, I display 3 images using `col-xs-4` so that 3 images are displayed on any screen size per row. However I want it now to display only 1 image when the screen size gets smaller. This is my original code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <img src="https://images.google.com/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <img src="https://images.google.com/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <img src="https://images.google.com/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

**Desired output**: 
Desktop View:
[image]

Mobile View:

[image]

I am aware that I can simply set the `display to none` when the screen size goes below a certain break point but I want the web application to load only 1 image to make it faster (just using `display:none;` will still load the other 2 images)

Any suggestion how to do this? 
My idea is to use jquery / javascript to generate html pages.
Here is the jsfiddle to play around: https://jsfiddle.net/Lb92rv84/1/

Comment: CSS can't remove the HTML elements, you need to use javascript to calculate the screen size first then, add the HTML elements depend on what's your needed.

Comment: @ManaTinra im aware that css alone cant do it I just added my code to say that Im currently using bootstrap grid. and would like some suggestions how to do it with the help of jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the html elements from the question.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var width = $(window).width();
  var newdiv1 = $('<div class="col-xs-4"></div>');
  var image = '<img src="https://images.google.com/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png">';
  var el = newdiv1.append(image);
  
  if (width >= 768){
   //html for screen wider than 768
   el.appendTo('.target').clone().appendTo('.target').clone().appendTo('.target');
  }else{
   //html for screen smaller than 768
   el.appendTo('.target');
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="target"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was able to figure it out myself and this is very close to what I did. So im selecting this as the answer. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Try assigning custom classes to each image DIV you want to hide:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4 image-1">
    <I'm src="https://images.google.com/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 image-1">
    <img   src="https://images.google.com/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <img src="https://images.google.com/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Then in your breakpoint:

```
.image-1 img{
  display:none;
 }
```

This way you can still use your div for other content and only hide images.

Comment: please see my question, I specifically mentioned that hiding the image is not an option

Comment: Then that's not possible in css.  Your concept is wrong.  Relaying on JavaScript for unnecessary styles is also wrong when you can change the structure for a better model. It doesn't make sense to leave one image and hide the other two.  Not a good UX.

Comment: Thats exactly my question. I did not say Im gonna use CSS to do all these. I just relay in the question the current state of my project and asking possible ideas on how to do this with jquery.